# Cannot visualize xarray dataframe after converting to NetCDF

Tags: python, netcdf, pandas, xarray

I am trying to convert sample.csv dataframe - [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMjfZNXwBCaQQKq585cA?e=iJHecK) no NetCDF here is what I did

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

dfcsv=pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
dfcsv=dfcsv.set_index(['latitude','longitude','zgodina'])
dfcsvx=dfcsv.to_xarray()
dfcsvx.to_netcdf(path='dxa.nc')
```

Conversion works fine, but I can't visualize data in NOAA Weather and Climate Toolkit I get following error

[image]